# Usage of „Ihr seid …“

Tags: meaning-in-context

In my journey of learning German I’ve started playing my favourite games using the German interface. In one of the games I’ve encountered the following line:

> Ihr seid jetzt nicht an der Tastatur: AFK

In English this is something like:

> You are now Away: AFK

This clearly is directed to me, the player, so it should be singular. Like *you* as in *the player*. But the German translation is using second person plural as in *all of you are now Away: AFK* which doesn’t make sense in the context of the game.

If they’ve wanted to use the polite formula I think it should had been *Sie sind …*.

Is this a faulty translation or there is something regarding German language that I didn’t quite understood? Why do they use plural form?

Comment: What game did you play? Some magic/medieval setting?

Comment: Yes, it is world of warcraft, so the game is in a fantasy context.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your assessments are correct so far. Modern-day German would unambiguously understand *ihr seid* as a plural form, with *Sie sind* being a formal one and *du bist* being informal.

Usually in games I would expect the *du* form, unless we're talking economy sims where the employees address their boss (you, the player) with *Sie*.

So in a Mario game Toad would tell you (being Mario):

> Du bist gerade abwesend!

While in Railroad Tycoon, the secretary would tell you (being the boss):

> Sie sind gerade abwesend.

**But** there is a third case. The usage of *Sie* in formal speech is not very old; the correct polite form used to be *Ihr*. This usage is now strongly associated with ancient history, the Middle Ages, maybe Renaissance etc. and — most importantly — fantasy contexts. It is used even if not 100 % necessary because it gives the game a fantastic feel. As you said the game is World of Warcraft, so it entirely makes sense to fall into a mediavistic-ish language and to let some lowly troll remind you:

> Ihr seid zur Zeit nicht in der Nähe des Bedienkastens.

Think of it as being a German equivalent of

> Thou art away from the keyboard.

Or something. (Only that *thou* is an informal form, while *Ihr* is formal).

Comment: Exactly. I may add that I have a few (literally dying out now...) elder relatives that I still address in second person plural, especially when speaking in dialect ([Danube Swabian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danube_Swabians)). But *do not try this with the old lady you meet at the bus stop*. If you happen to visit one of the medieval fairs, be prepared to be addressed as "Ihr" and respond in kind, if you like.

Comment: +1 for the bus stop :D. Is it possible that Danube Swabian preserved older forms because they were isolated from the rest of the German speaking area?

Comment: Absolutely. There are plenty of "older" versions plus a bunch of loanwords/specific words. I sometimes jokingly say that I grew up with 3 languages: Standard German, Swabian and Danube Swabian... In my experience, the most difficult part is mentally switching the cultural context - my mom occasionally slips up and uses "Ihr" when she wants to be respectful and *means* "Sie" but it may come across as too familiar (understood as plural form of "du").

Comment: Good explanation. It happens that "Ihr seid" remains the only correct formal singular form in Yiddish.

Comment: Incidentally, English also settled on using the second person plural “you”.